# Multidex errors while generating hashkey for Facebook Auth with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, facebook-authentication

I have an issue implementing *Facebook auth* with Firebase. Basically, something on Facebook libraries and dependencies makes my app have multidex errors. [image: Several errors like to multidex]

I saw this error when I tried to generate a hash key to provide to Facebook. At first, I thought it was the function to print the hash key, which I took from an old post in a Stack Overflow question. But even after I deleted it, the error persisted. The only way to remove the error disappear is to delete `mavencentral` from repositories and *Facebook auth* from dependencies. I based my code on [this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=it7NjMsWn8Q&list=PLmdU__e_zPf8S17QggtGjjwIkD1rWzzl2&index=3&t=187s) The dependency that I added is *Facebook auth* and the library is `mavenCentral()`. If you have any ideas, I'll be grateful for your help;)
Here is the print hashkey function (in case you're wondering):

```
fun printHashKey(pContext: Context) {
        try {
            val info = pContext.packageManager.getPackageInfo(pContext.packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
            for (signature in info.signatures) {
                val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
                md.update(signature.toByteArray())
                val hashKey = String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0))
                println( "printHashKey() Hash Key: $hashKey")
            }
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {

        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Now i retrived my haskey by deleting the facebook library and dependencies so I have a question and i didn't deleted my question cause i'm not sure. Is it normal to get a multidex errors when adding facebook dependenceis and libraries(taking into consideration that no code is offcially written on this authentication). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I simply activated Multidex and it worked out!